# Custom labels for phone numbers in contacts disappear immediately after creation

Tags: iphone, contacts

I want to create a custom label in contacts to designate GoToMeeting dial in numbers and access codes.  I am able to create the custom label as "GoToMeeting" and save it, but when I get out of contacts go back in, the custom label is gone.  The label reverts back to the generic one "work phone".
I am able to create custom labels for addresses, notes, etc, but not phone numbers. iPhone 6+

Comment: Are you able to do it on your Mac or using the iCloud website?  That could be a workaround until you get this resolved.

Comment: Also, what provider are you using for contacts? I used to have problems with custom labels using Google ActiveSync.